# How to implement show more button on my page using js/jquery show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which contains 40 items. But I don't want all the 40 stories to be displayed on one page at a time. 
I don't have ajax knowledge. So without using any ajax how can I implement *show more* functionality on my page to show only 10 items at a time on my page by using pure **jquery/js** `hide()` or `show()` and not ajax?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No I'm trying to get a general idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

HTML:

```
<div id="text1">text</div>
<div id="text2">text</div>
<div id="text3">text</div>    
<div id="text4">text</div>
<br><br>
<div id="button">Show more</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 var count=2;
 $( "#button" ).click(function() {
 $( "#text"+count ).show();
 count++;
        });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NzHKu/1/)

Comment: hey yeah I can accept in 6 mins as per stack overflow :) . One more questn.: What if I have "x" number of items. Not just 40 & irrespective of the number , I want to display only 10 per page. All the items that I have are inside a <ul> </ul>. So each item is an <li>.   In that case?

Comment: @kiki You should put them inside `<div id="text1"></div>` 10 items

Comment: <ul id="xyz"> all the stories in <li> </ul>

Answer (score 0):

Don't have much time to explain right now, drafted something (intentionally ajax-less) together for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/J2MMc/

```
$(function(){
$show = 4;
$articles = $("#newsblock>.news");

$update = function()
{
    $vis = 0;
    $pos = 0;
    $articles.each(function(ind,obj)
    {
        $pos++;
        $(this).css({"display":($pos>$show)?'none':'block'});

        if ($pos<=$show) { $vis++; }
    });

    if ($vis == $articles.length)
    {
        $("#btnMore").css({"display":"none"});   
    }
};
$update();

$btnMore = $("<div />").attr({"id":"btnMore"});
$btnMore.html("Show more");
$btnMore.click(function()
{
    $show = $show + 2;
    $update();
});
$("body").append($btnMore);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J2MMc/

```
<div id="newsblock">
<div class="news" data-id="1">Lorem Ipsum blah blah</div>
<div class="news" data-id="2">Lorem Ipsum blah blah</div>
<div class="news" data-id="3">Lorem Ipsum blah blah</div>
<div class="news" data-id="4">Lorem Ipsum blah blah</div>
<div class="news" data-id="5">Lorem Ipsum blah blah</div>
<div class="news" data-id="6">Lorem Ipsum blah blah</div>
<div class="news" data-id="7">Lorem Ipsum blah blah</div>
<div class="news" data-id="8">Lorem Ipsum blah blah</div>
<div class="news" data-id="9">Lorem Ipsum blah blah</div>
<div class="news" data-id="10">Lorem Ipsum blah blah</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J2MMc/

Good luck.